# Flutter : How to increase indentation width of tab '\t' in text

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have the following widget that I use to print text:

```dart
class NormalText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String txt;

  NormalText(this.txt) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Text(txt,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)));
  }
}
```

But if I use it like:

```
NormalText('hello\tworld\t42')
```

The \t indentation is too tiny. Is there any way to increase the indentation to take more space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to keep the space between the words, and only increase the tabs, you can use Wrap widget

```dart
            Wrap(
              children: "hello hello\tworld\t42"
                  .split("\t")
                  .map((text) => Text(text))
                  .expand((element) => [
                        element,
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 50,
                        )
                      ])
                  .toList()
                    ..removeLast(),
            ),
```

Comment: `SizedBox` was an incredibly simple solution for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wordSpacing` parameter

```dart
Text(
  'Build some widgets!',
  style: TextStyle(
      height: 1.2 ,
      wordSpacing: 6,
      letterSpacing: 1.0,
   )
),
```

Comment: In the example I gave it works but obviously I am using this widget for more complex text, I know well wordSpacing, but I want to use \t and not spaces

Comment: Do you want space between specific words?

Comment: I use a mix of spaces and tabs between words. For now I found a "solution" which is simply to use 4 spaces instead of \t but it feels a bit sad.

Comment: I am still not sure about the requirement. You can probably explore [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) on your TextField and then replace each tab character with a `TextSpan` with a text style that set the `letterSpacing` to 20 for example.

In your widget with your text field:

```
final tabController = TabTextController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextField(controller: tabController);
}
```

Your custom TextEditingController:

```
class TabTextController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    List<TextSpan> children = [];

    text.splitMapJoin(
      RegExp(r'\t'),
      onMatch: (match) {
        children.add(
            TextSpan(text: '\t', style: style?.copyWith(letterSpacing: 20)));
        return '';
      },
      onNonMatch: (string) {
        children.add(TextSpan(text: text, style: style));
        return '';
      },
    );

    return TextSpan(children: children, style: style);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `\t` to get more `Tab Spaces`.

Check the code below for an example on how to do that :

```
// combine two \t
print('hello\t\tworld\t42');
```

Comment: I tried this already. Would like to configure the width or number of spaces contained in one \t directly.